# Need a datastructure for internal scope representation

Tags: c#, parsing, data-structures

I am working on a custom programming language for interactive fiction games. The language isn't meant to be compiled, its more of a interpreted language like Python. I am building the parser in C#. While constructing this interpreter, I have run into questions about how to represent scopes in memory. I have every variable stored in a special variable class.

```
    public class variable
    {
        public string str;
        public DataType datatype; //an enum with all datatypes supported by the language
        public int id;
        private static int increment;
        public variable(string str, DataType datatype)
        {
            this.str = str;
            this.datatype = datatype;
            this.id = increment;
            increment++;
        }
    }
```

Also, I have a special scope class for holding variables that are in a specific scope:

```
    public class scope
    {
        public List<variable> variables;
        public scope()
        {
            variables = new List<variable>();
        }
    }
```

The question is, what kind of data-structure could I use to easily store these scopes, and quickly loop through all the scopes (and thus variables in those scopes) that are accessible from a certain scope? I need something kind-of like a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, scopes have been represented by `Stack` data structures. It works especially well with curly brace syntax as you can basically push a new one on encountering `{` and pop on `}`.

As far as determining the variables available, a very simple (albeit, brute force) method would be to use `SelectMany`:

```
bool variableExists = currentScopes.SelectMany(s => s.Variables).Any(v => v.Value.Name == variableName);
```

As an aside, you are actually writing an *interpreter* for an *interpreted* language. All programming languages are parsed.